# How to split string by character and check format by regular expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I know that Laravel supports routing using regex like below

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id) {
    //
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

if my endpoint like */{size}/photo*, e.g. */100x100/foo.jpg*
how could i check if the size is valid using regex?

I am new to regex. Thanks

Comment: explode on the `/` to get to the size, then on the `x` to get the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
Route::get('{size}/{filename}.jpg', function($size, $filename) {
    list($width, $height) = explode('x', $size);
    // Now use $width and $height, and enjoy life!
})
->where('size', '\d+x\d+');
```

Comment: would I ask somemore? any suggestion that can filter zero out also?

Comment: `[1-9]\d*+x[1-9]\d*`  maybe this way?